# New Customer Orders, but only if they purchased 1 week after registering

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, aginity

So what I'm trying to do is understand what products my **new customers** purchase, 1 week after they registered.

Currently, this is my query:

```
SELECT
    item_description_1,
    t3.new_division,
    quantity_ordered
FROM 
    mdwh.us_raw.order_report
    INNER JOIN l_act_account t2 ON customer_id = SUBSTRING(t2.channel_uid,4,18)
    FULL OUTER JOIN item_master_zs t3 ON SUBSTRING(upc,1,6) = t3.item_code
WHERE 
    quantity_ordered > 0
    AND customer_id IS NOT NULL
    AND customer_id != ('')
    AND customer_id LIKE 'US%'
    AND oms_order_date IS NOT NULL
    AND extended_amount < 1000 --NO BULK ORDERS
    AND UPPER(line_status) NOT IN ('','RETURN', 'CANCELLED')
    AND (quantity_ordered * unit_price_amount) > 0
    AND oms_order_date BETWEEN '2019-03-01' AND '2019-03-31'
    AND t2.create_timestamp BETWEEN '2019-03-01' AND '2019-03-31'
    AND SUBSTRING(upc,1,6) IN (SELECT item_code FROM item_master_zs WHERE new_division BETWEEN '11' AND '39') --Overall
GROUP BY
    item_description_1,
    t3.new_division,
    quantity_ordered
ORDER BY
    quantity_ordered desc
LIMIT 60
```

This query is giving me the top 60 items purchased within March, from new customers I gained in March. Here's what the output looks like right now:

[image]

All I need now is an output that looks exactly like the above, but only showing me the items purchased 7 days AFTER their create_timestamp date (when they registered).

**The point of this is as follows:** some new customers may register an account and immediately make a purchase because of some sort of coupon or perhaps a referral. However, if I can see which products users purchased (where they seem to have waited a week before making a purchase), then I can see which products triggered them to come and make that purchase.

Please let me know if I made anything unclear, or if you need additional info.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: What do *you* mean by "1 week" after they registered?  Do you mean "during the week", "on the date 7 days later", "at the exact instant 168 hours after registration"?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff, I've added the info you requested, with some more explanation.

Comment: Updated post to provide more detail. Please let me know if I made anything unclear. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: **Side-note:** Be careful of mixing timestamps and dates. `oms_order_date BETWEEN '2019-03-01' AND '2019-03-31'` will cover the full month, but `t2.create_timestamp BETWEEN '2019-03-01' AND '2019-03-31'` will not include orders on the 31st because the timestamp would default to midnight at the _start_ of that day (since the time has not been provided).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you only want to include orders where the order date (`oms_order_date`) is within 7 days after registration date (`create_timestamp`).

Assuming that the order date is a `DATE` and the registration is a `TIMESTAMP`, you can only work in full days, not down to the hour.

Therefore, you'd use:

```sql
WHERE oms_order_date - create_timestamp <= INTERVAL '7 days'
```

Comment: Thank you - just to clarify: I'm looking for orders where the order date is at least 7 days after the registration, not within a week of registering. Would this string you supplied perform that? I think I may just need to switch the operator from < to >, no?

Comment: The suggested statement is correct. It is saying "The time difference between order date and registration date is less than or equal to 7 days". If you wish, you can rewrite it as: `WHERE oms_order_date <= create_timestamp + INTERVAL '7 days'` (It's the same thing)

Comment: Wouldnt that give me orders placed by the user within 7 days of registering? I'd want it so that its 7+ days after registering. Sorry, might not be understanding the subtlety. @JohnRotenstein

Comment: Oh, that was unclear. Your requirements said "showing me the items purchased 7 days AFTER their create_timestamp date", which I interpreted as "items purchases _within_ 7 days after the create date". If you wish to find items purchased _at least 7 days_ from the create date, then yes -- you would reverse the comparison operator (from `<=` to either `>` or `>=`).